# How to exploit dom based xss from this information?Is it exploitable?

Tags: javascript, dom, xss

I got a notification from burp scanner as

**The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based cross-site scripting. Data is read from document.URL and passed to the 'prepend()' function of JQuery via the following statement:
$("body:not(..." ) .prepend( *'%3cdiv clas...' + document.URL.substr(0 , document.URL.indexOf("?" ) ) + '%3e*...' )**

but I don't understand how to exploit this ,help me out with this.
Thank you.

Comment: This [exploiting XSS in jQuery selector](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120938/exploiting-xss-in-jquery-selector) question and answer might help.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
.prepend( '%3cdiv clas...' + document.URL.substr(0 , document.URL.indexOf("?" ) )
```

part

```
document.URL.substr(0 , document.URL.indexOf("?" )
```

is in our control, which takes document url from starting to first ? char.
By changing URL it can be exploited.

For further information, you can look https://excess-xss.com/ .